# Поиск по richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, richtextbox

Как сделать поиск через `TextBox` по `RichTextBox`? Есть [пример кода](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851908/highlight-all-searched-word-in-richtextbox) с англоязычного форума. Подскажите как это можно использовать или же сделать.

```
static class Utility {
    public static void HighlightText(this RichTextBox myRtb, string word, Color color) {  

       if (word == string.Empty)
            return;

       int s_start = myRtb.SelectionStart, startIndex = 0, index;

       while((index = myRtb.Text.IndexOf(word, startIndex)) != -1) {
           myRtb.Select(index, word.Length);
           myRtb.SelectionColor = color;

           startIndex = index + word.Length;
       }

       myRtb.SelectionStart = s_start;
       myRtb.SelectionLength = 0;
       myRtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Comment: Так у вас **вами же** метод расширения приведен, что вы еще хотите?

Comment: Как это привязать к TextBox? Потому и спрашиваю, что не знаю как это использовать и куда вставлять.

Comment: К TextBox? Никак, они не находятся в одной цепочке иерархии.

Comment: забирайте текст из TextBox и передавайте в параметр word этого метода. И разберитесь с языком для начала, чтобы понимать что вы копируете и куда это потом вставлять. Литература [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416585/198316)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, на событие `TextChaged` повесить:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Utility.HighlightText(richTextBox1, textBox1.Text, Color.Blue);
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю код из вопроса нужно в отдельный класс помещать или как? Если просто вставить то ошибки выдает.

Comment: Код из вопроса уже готовый класс. Просто держите его в том же `namespace`, в котором находится Ваша форма

Answer (score 1):

```
Utility.HighlightText(richTextBox1, textBox1.Text, Color.Red);
```